# Mod rewrite converting underscores to dashes affecting embedded images

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have implemented the following code to my .htaccess file to convert all underscores to dashes.

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

The above code works, but I come across a problem when embedding images from my /images directory.

For instance if one of the image file names contains an underscore it fails to load correctly.

How can I emit images and javacript file names from the above rule???

Is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Add some conditions to the 2 rules. You can either go with a "check if the request if for a file that doesn't exist", or "check if the request ends in a (jpe?g|png|bmp|gif)". The first should cover other things like URLs accessing other resources (javascript, css, etc), so they won't also have their underscores converted, the 2nd only deals with images. You need to add the condition above BOTH rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|bmp|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|bmp|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```